# Valid JSON in jsonlint, but JSON.parse() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a JSON which is verified in the JSONlint, but I cannot use JSON.parse() as it is not working. What is the problem with the JSON here, if JSON.prase() cannot be used what are my alternatives.

JSON string : `"{Products: [{Id: 1,Increment: 5,Max: 1000,Min: 25,allowed: false,Desc: product description,Name:Product Name,Qty: 0}]}"`

Comment: is there an error message?

Comment: Oh, that is not valid JSON.... none of the keys are quoted. Not sure how that would have passes a JSON linter.

Comment: Yeah, same here, not valid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a JSON be valid, your object keys must be inside double quotes:

```
{ "validKey": 123 }
  ^        ^
  |        |
  ------------- These double-quotes are required!
```

JSONLint said that it's alright because you pasted the JSON as you pasted here, wrapped in quotes:

```
"{Products: [{Id: 1,Increment: 5,Max: 1000,Min: 25,allowed: false,Desc: product description,Name:Product Name,Qty: 0}]}"
```

And this is a json string with a JSON inside, not a JSON!

If you try to JSONLint without the Quotes you will get this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   Products: [{        Id: 1
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your strings and keys should be quoted. This is valid JSON that will be correctly parsed by `JSON.parse()`

```
{
  "Products": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Increment": 5,
      "Max": 1000,
      "Min": 25,
      "allowed": false,
      "Desc": "product description",
      "Name": "Product Name",
      "Qty": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about the standard here: https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you are passing the JSON content inside a "string" variable, you need to using single quotes insted of double quotes of the outside string

```js
var data = "{ "nodes": [{ "id": 1, "text": "DefinitionFinder" },{ "id": 2, "text": "ProjectReference" },{ "id": 3, "text": "ReferenceManager" },{ "id": 4, "text": "ReferenceType" },{ "id": 5, "text": "EventStream" },{ "id": 6, "text": "AutoDisposable" },{ "id": 7, "text": "Handler" }], "links": [{ "from": 1, "to": 3 },{ "from": 2, "to": 4 },{ "from": 3, "to": 1 },{ "from": 3, "to": 2 }] }"
```

This is the correct way

```js
var data = '{ "nodes": [{ "id": 1, "text": "DefinitionFinder" },{ "id": 2, "text": "ProjectReference" },{ "id": 3, "text": "ReferenceManager" },{ "id": 4, "text": "ReferenceType" },{ "id": 5, "text": "EventStream" },{ "id": 6, "text": "AutoDisposable" },{ "id": 7, "text": "Handler" }], "links": [{ "from": 1, "to": 3 },{ "from": 2, "to": 4 },{ "from": 3, "to": 1 },{ "from": 3, "to": 2 }] }'
```